# Moving element index in a nested list based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Looking to create an input loop that'll ask the user if they want to move an element named "K" up columns until they are trying to move into an index which is out of range, however when I input "N" the "K" element disappears and does not move up columns as intended.

```
table = [
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"]
]

tableQuit = ''
krow = -1
kcol = 0
k = "K"

for i in range(len(table[0])):
    for j in range(len(table)):
        table[krow][kcol] = k
while tableQuit != "Q":
    for i in table:
        while True:
            tableQuit = input("Do you want to go north")
            if tableQuit == "N" or tableQuit == "Q":
                break
            else:
                print("\nInvalid input.")
                print(table)
        if tableQuit == 'N':
            table[krow][kcol] = table[krow + 1][kcol]
            print(table)
        if tableQuit == 'Q':
            print("\nGood bye!")
            break
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `k` as soon as the first time the N is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `while` loop for your game loop:

```
table = [
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"]
]

def print_map(grid): # Just for convenience
    for i in grid:
        print(i)

k = "K"
krow, kcol = 2, 0
table[krow][kcol] = k     
tableQuit = ''   
while tableQuit != "Q":
    print_map(table)
    tableQuit = input("Press N to go north. Press Q to quit: ")
    if tableQuit == 'N':
        table[krow][kcol] = '-' 
        krow = (krow - 1) % len(table)
        table[krow][kcol] = 'K'

print("\nGood bye!")
```

Answer (score 0):

While GrandPhuba answer is the way to go. I tried to get your code to run with the minimum amount of edit. See code comments for changes:

```
table = [
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"],
    ["-", "-", "-"]
]

tableQuit = ''
# set the right row number
krow = 2
kcol = 0
k = "K"

for i in range(len(table[0])):
    for j in range(len(table)):
        table[krow][kcol] = k

print(table)
while tableQuit != "Q":
    for i in table:
        while True:
            tableQuit = input("Do you want to go north")
            if tableQuit == "N" or tableQuit == "Q":
                break
            else:
                print("\nInvalid input.")
                print(table)
        if tableQuit == 'N':
            # set old row/kol to -
            table[krow][kcol] = '-'
            # update k row
            if krow > 0:
                krow -=1
            else:
                krow = 2
            # set new row/k to K
            table[krow][kcol] = 'K'
            print(table)
        if tableQuit == 'Q':
            print("\nGood bye!")
            break
```